# What's the recommend to do string assignment in the C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
std::string s = t;
```

I think after this, s and t point to the same address.

Once `t` is deleted, `s` is also empty. How do I make a deep copy?

Comment: C++ does not include a `String` class.

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: I'm assuming `t` is also a `std::string`, correct me if I'm wrong.

> I think after this, s and t points to the address.

They do not, they are not pointers.

> once t is delete, s is also empty

`t` can't be deleted, or if you do delete it, that's your problem right there. Don't delete `t`, it will go out of scope automatically.

In your code, you use `std::string`'s copy constructor - which, as the name suggests, creates a copy of the original string.

Comment: Why does it matter what `t` is? Assigning to `s` makes a copy no matter what. If deleting `t` is a defined operation, it has no effect on `s`.

Comment: @RobKennedy it matters in my answer because I said `t` can't be deleted. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect, they are completely separate copies of the string. When one is deleted, the other still exists. The assignment operator is exactly how you should copy these.

Comment: His code doesn't use the assignment operator.

Comment: Yes I know, but the assignment operator is one way to copy. I suppose I should say that the copy constructor also copies.

Comment: You shoud, from the answer one can deduce that his code uses the assignment operator.